# jQuery/JavaScript Get input values and then copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of `input` elements and with javascript on click i'm getting the values of these inputs and paste it in a `div` somewhere
Please run the code snipped below to check

```js
$('#getthelist').click(function() {
  $('.inputs>li .color').map(function() {
    return {
      name: this.closest('[id]').id,
      value: $(this).val()
    }
  }).get().forEach(function(e) {
    $('.list').append('<div>' + '\"' + e.name + '\": \"' + e.value + '\",</div>');
  });
});
```

```css
ul,li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #fafafb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="color_white">
<ul class="inputs">

    <input type="radio" value="getthelist" id="getthelist"> Click to get the color values

  
  <li id="color_white">
   <div>
    <input type="text" value="#fff" class="color">
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li id="color_black">
   <div>
    <input type="text" value="#000" class="color">
   </div>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<div class="list"></div>
```

So i have got one question and a problem i cant figure out how to fix.

- The problem is, each time you click the button it pastes the values in the `div` repeatedly. It is a mess to me for what i'm trying to do. so, How do i force it not to repeat the same values when you click every time.
- Question: How do i copy the input values to `clipboard` with the same click function?

Comment: As for your 1st Question what you can do is store the values in an object array like `[{"col1":"#00","col2":"#ff"},....n]` and then on every insert just do a filter and check if the values exists and for your 2nd question you can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/2417602

Comment: can you try my answer if not working then please review I have updated with the more efficient way and cross-browser compatibility with ff and chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my snippet codes.

```js
function copyToClipboad(texts) {
  var textareaElCloned = $('<textarea>' + texts + '</textarea>');
  $('.list').append(textareaElCloned);
  /* Select the text field */
  textareaElCloned[0].select();
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
}

$('#getthelist').click(function() {
  var html = '';
  var texts = '';
  var itemEls = $('.inputs > li .color');
  
  itemEls.map(function() {
    return {
      name: this.closest('[id]').id,
      value: $(this).val()
    }
  }).get().forEach(function(e, index) {
    var text = '\"' + e.name + '\": \"' + e.value + '\",';
    texts += text;
    html += ('<div>' + text + '</div>');
    
    if (index === itemEls.length-1) {
       copyToClipboad(texts);
    }
  });
  
  $('.list').html(html); // the textarea will be removed at this moment
});
```

```css
ul,li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: #fafafb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="color_white">
<ul class="inputs">

    <input type="radio" value="getthelist" id="getthelist"> Click to get the color values

  
  <li id="color_white">
   <div>
    <input type="text" value="#fff" class="color">
   </div>
  </li>
  
  <li id="color_black">
   <div>
    <input type="text" value="#000" class="color">
   </div>
  </li>
  
</ul>

<div class="list" tabindex="1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to give you both questions answer.

> Answer of Q1
>   you should reset HTML content before set new value.
>
> Answer of Q2
>   you should use document.executeCommand("copy") to copy the text.

Hope it may help to resolve your issue.

```js
function copyData(copyText) {
  $("body").append($("<textarea/>").val(copyText).attr({id:"txtareaCopyData"}));
  var copyText = document.querySelector("#txtareaCopyData");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $("#txtareaCopyData").remove();
}

$('#getthelist').click(function() {
  // Clear html div content
  $('.list').html("");
  var copyText = "";
  $('.inputs>li .color').map(function() {
    return {
      name: this.closest('[id]').id,
      value: $(this).val()
    }
  }).get().forEach(function(e) {
    var _data = '<div>' + '\"' + e.name + '\": \"' + e.value + '\",</div>';
    $('.list').append(_data);
    copyText += _data;
  });
  copyData(copyText);
  document.querySelector("#txtCopyArea").addEventListener("click", copyData);
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fafafb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="color_white">
  <ul class="inputs">

    <input type="radio" value="getthelist" id="getthelist"> Click to get the color values


    <li id="color_white">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="#fff" class="color">
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="color_black">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="#000" class="color">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" id="txtCopyArea" name="txtCopyArea" />

  <div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I will mark this answer if you fix the copy to clipboard function. it does not work

Comment: @Nippledisaster what an issue you have faced let me know

Comment: @Nippledisaster I have tested same code with my application and it may copy properly it will working in ff and chrome well.

Answer (score 1):

1. save your data in localStorage.setItem (return value of .map must save in localstorage)
2. get your data with localStorage.getItem (get data from localstorage with key that you set for item)
3. create a template with handlebar.js, and when click on checkbox, render template with data that get from localstorage.

for new data, you must update localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the solution from Dipak chavda but it does not work for me also. The problem is that the input is type of hidden. So I changed it to hidden textarea. When you try to copy, I make it visible for a while, focus it, select it's value and then exec the copy. And it works ;)

```js
function copyData(copyText) {
  var $txtCopyArea = $("#txtCopyArea");
  // set the text as value
  $txtCopyArea.val(copyText);
  // make textarea visible
  $txtCopyArea.removeClass('hidden');
  /* focus & select the text field */
  $txtCopyArea.focus().select();
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText);
  // hide textarea
  $txtCopyArea.addClass('hidden');
}

$('#getthelist').click(function() {
  // Clear html div content
  $('.list').html("");
  var copyText = "";
  $('.inputs>li .color').map(function() {
    return {
      name: this.closest('[id]').id,
      value: $(this).val()
    }
  }).get().forEach(function(e) {
    var _data = '<div>' + '\"' + e.name + '\": \"' + e.value + '\",</div>';
    $('.list').append(_data);
    copyText += _data;
  });
  copyData(copyText);
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 270px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #fafafb;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="color_white">
  <ul class="inputs">

    <input type="radio" value="getthelist" id="getthelist"> Click to get the color values


    <li id="color_white">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="#fff" class="color">
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="color_black">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="#000" class="color">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <textarea id="txtCopyArea" class="hidden"></textarea>

  <div class="list"></div>
```